# Formatting Django ManyToManyField as selectable items

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have 2 questions. I have 2 models Toolcart and Tools I'm making a ManyToMany relation from Toolcart to Tools, I want to add one or more tools to the cart

Question 1.- Is this the right approach for what I'm attempting to do ?
Question 2.- I used a generic class to create the Toolcart object (CreateView) and get a box with all the content from  Tools model. how would i go about making selectable items. Does what I'm trying to do makies sense?

my models.py:

```
class Tools(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    codigo_proveedor = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    categoria = models.ForeignKey('Categorias', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    c_minima = models.IntegerField()
    c_actual = models.IntegerField()
    proveedor = models.ForeignKey('Proveedores', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre + '   -----   ' + str(self.categoria) + '   -----    ' + str(self.c_actual)


class Toolcart(models.Model):
    designacion = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    contenido = models.ManyToManyField(Tools)
    active = models.BooleanField()

    def  __str__(self):
        return self.designacion
```

my views.py:

```
# VER CARRITO
class CarritoCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Toolcart
    template_name = 'inventory/cars_form.html'
    fields = [
        'designacion',
        'contenido',
        'active',
    ]
success_url = reverse_lazy('inventory:home')
```

Comment: did you get to solve your problem? Was my answer below useful to you?

Comment: Hey thanks for your followup. honestly haven't had the time to implement it. As soon as i have  a chance i will try it out and let you know how it whent.

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding question 1**

Yes, I think the two models and the `ManyToManyRelationship` are a good way to face the task that you described.

**Regarding question 2**

You could go two ways:

1. Display a list of `Tools` where each tool item has a button "add to cart" that submits a hidden form (each row has its own hidden form).

   ```
   <form method='post' action='/url/to/add/to/cart/'>
       {% csrf_token %}
       <input type='hidden' value='{{ tool.pk }}' name='tool_pk'>
       <button>add to cart</button>
   </form>
   ```
2. Display a list of `Tools` inside a giant form and let every tool item have a checkbox. Then you can have one button "add selected items to cart" which submits the whole form.